# Debian: USB HD Random Disconnect

Tags: debian, hard-drive, ext4

I've a debian box (Sheevaplug) everything seems to be ok, however I've an external hard drive attached to the USB port and sometimes the drive seems to disconnect itself randomly... and connect, I get this under messages:

```
Mar 28 05:22:24 dbbox kernel: [ 2158.397248] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
Mar 28 05:22:24 dbbox kernel: [ 2158.416013] EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 1444621 (offset 211042304 size 245760 starting block 73870434)
Mar 28 05:22:24 dbbox kernel: [ 2158.492838] EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 1444621 (offset 211042304 size 245760 starting block 73870464)
Mar 28 05:22:24 dbbox kernel: [ 2158.506691] EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 1444621 (offset 214433792 size 524288 starting block 73871262)
Mar 28 05:22:24 dbbox kernel: [ 2158.520535] EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 1444621 (offset 214433792 size 524288 starting block 73871292)
Mar 28 05:22:24 dbbox kernel: [ 2158.534382] EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 1444621 (offset 214433792 size 524288 starting block 73871322)
Mar 28 05:22:24 dbbox kernel: [ 2158.548229] EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 1444621 (offset 214433792 size 524288 starting block 73871352)
Mar 28 05:22:24 dbbox kernel: [ 2158.562075] EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 1444621 (offset 214433792 size 524288 starting block 73871360)
Mar 28 05:22:24 dbbox kernel: [ 2158.575901] EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 1444621 (offset 320077824 size 262144 starting block 74443870)
Mar 28 05:22:24 dbbox kernel: [ 2158.589744] EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 1444621 (offset 320077824 size 262144 starting block 74443900)
Mar 28 05:22:24 dbbox kernel: [ 2158.603591] EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 1444621 (offset 320077824 size 262144 starting block 74443904)
Mar 28 05:22:24 dbbox kernel: [ 2158.982286] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using orion-ehci
Mar 28 05:22:25 dbbox kernel: [ 2159.128302] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=059f, idProduct=1057
Mar 28 05:22:25 dbbox kernel: [ 2159.135078] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
Mar 28 05:22:25 dbbox kernel: [ 2159.142358] usb 1-1: Product: Rikiki USB 3
Mar 28 05:22:25 dbbox kernel: [ 2159.146590] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: LaCie
Mar 28 05:22:25 dbbox kernel: [ 2159.150590] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 00000000XXXXXXXXXXXXX
Mar 28 05:22:25 dbbox kernel: [ 2159.166120] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Mar 28 05:22:25 dbbox kernel: [ 2159.178384] scsi1 : usb-storage 1-1:1.0
Mar 28 05:22:26 dbbox kernel: [ 2160.183268] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  Q300.            SAFM PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
Mar 28 05:22:26 dbbox kernel: [ 2160.209470] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 937703088 512-byte logical blocks: (480 GB/447 GiB)
Mar 28 05:22:26 dbbox kernel: [ 2160.224067] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Mar 28 05:22:26 dbbox kernel: [ 2160.237142] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Mar 28 05:22:26 dbbox kernel: [ 2160.320401]  sdb: sdb1
Mar 28 05:22:26 dbbox kernel: [ 2160.334464] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

How can I debug this issue and find whats going on?

Thank you.

Comment: Are your USB drivers up to date? A slew of USB drivers were patched recently.

Comment: @ParthianShot I just run `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade` nothing USB related come up I guess... Please note sheevaplug is running kernel `3.16.0-4-kirkwood` I'm not sure if they get a USB update as well...